# A String to int conversion returning 156112 instead of 1 in objective c

Tags: objective-c, string, integer, type-conversion

I have a NSMutableDictionary, with values. One of the values is an NSString "1".

I get it like this:

```
NSString *currentCount = [perLetterCount valueForKey:firstLetter];
```

then I convert it to an int:

```
int newInt = (int)currentCount;
```

And I display both like this:

```
NSLog(@"s: %@, i: %i", currentCount, newInt);
```

I get this as a result:

```
 c: 1, i: 156112
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Thank you

Comment: The reason why you're getting the value 156112, is because when you cast to int like that, all your doing is grabbing the address of currentCount, not actually converting its value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `int newInt = currentCount.intValue` instead.

Answer (score 7):

What you are doing is converting a pointer (the address at which the string object currentCount's data is stored) to an integer.  And it appears that integer is 156112.

To obtain the numeric value of an NSString you need to call one of its value methods:

```
[ currentCount intValue ]  or currentCount.intValue // for an int;
[ currentCount integerValue ] or currentCount.integerValue // for an NSInteger;
[ currentCount floatValue ] or currentCount.floatValue // for a float, and so on.
```

Answer (score 2):

Like mentioned above, you can use:

```
int newInt = [currentCount intValue];
```

However, if the string doesn't contain a number it returns a zero.  This will be difficult if zero is a valid number in the string and it is also valid for the string to not have a number.

The way to get ints from strings when it's valid that the string doesn't contain one is:

```
NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:currentCount];

int newInt;
if (![scanner scanInt:&newInt]) {
    NSLog(@"Did not find integer in string:%@", currentCount);
}
```

Comment: Yes, I was assuming you knew there was a valid integer in there.